# extension of trigonometric functions as basis functions to higher dimensions

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials

Trigonometric functions forms an orthonormal basis functions for $L^2[a,b]$, with corresponding normalization coefficients.

I want to know if this result can be extended to higher dimensions. For example, consider $L^2[0,1]^2$, does it have an orthonormal basis as trigonometric series, possibly a tensor product forms, i.e. $\sin(nx)\cos(my)$, etc.

The motivation behind is that a common example to demonstrate spectral method is 1D heat equation, using trigonometric functions. On the other hand, 2D heat equation can also be solved using Fourier series, but I have not found any references discussing trigonometric orthonormal basis in higher dimensions. Besides, I am also interested in general orthonormal basis for $L^2[a,b]^d$ with $d>1$ and $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ possibly bounded. I think Sobolev space needs to be taken care of more carefully with the regularity of $\partial \Omega$ (probably I should start a new question on this).

Comment: You can show that the collection $\{ x \mapsto e^{i 2 \pi(n_1 x_1 + n_2 x_2)} \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^2}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,1]^2$. (And similarly, $\{ x \mapsto e^{i 2 \pi \sum_{k=0}^d n_k x_k} \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^d}$ for $L^2[0,1]^d$).

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the comment. Considering a n-cube, can the trigonometric functions be a basis for Sobolev spaces, given constant boundary? Besides, do we know anything about a general domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Out of my range, sorry...